# Creating a trigger with a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, insert, case

I have these two tables:

```
USERS(username, role_id)
COMMISSION_RATES(username, commission_rate)
```

`users.username` is the primary key, `commission_rates.username` is a foreign key.

I want to write a trigger, after an insert on users, check if `role_id = 2`, then insert into `commission_rates` the `users.username`, and 0 for commission rate.

This is what I have so far, it doesn't work though:

```
create or replace TRIGGER SETCOMISSIONRATE 
AFTER INSERT ON USERS 
BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN users.role_id = 2 THEN
      INSERT INTO COMISSION_RATE
          (username,
           comission_rate)
        VALUES (
          :NEW.username,
        0)
END;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Think you need a semi colon after your insert statement

Answer (score 2):

It should go like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SETCOMISSIONRATE 
AFTER INSERT ON USERS FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.role_id = 2)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO COMISSION_RATE (username, comission_rate)
    VALUES (:new.username, 0);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, when I type this into sql it underlines 
INSERT INTO COMISSION_RATE (broker_username, comission_rate) in red, and doesn't work

Comment: I also get these errors:
Error(2,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(3,31): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error(4,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Comment: I haven't programmed in oracle in a while, but adding `;` after inserted values should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

WHEN condition must be in the definition part, not in the body. They can only by used for row trigger.

```
create or replace
TRIGGER SETCOMISSIONRATE 
AFTER INSERT ON USERS 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.role_id = 2)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO COMISSION_RATE
    (username,
    comission_rate)
    VALUES (
    :NEW.username,
    0)

END;
```