# Create update trigger with when statement

Tags: sql

I need to create trigger on sql. The trigger update the value depend on the new value. If the value is true, then another column of the this table is false. If the value is false, the another column of this table is true. I tried to use when or if statement but got error. Would someone help me to solve the problem.

There is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER pUSer_update
AFTER UPDATE ON pUser
   REFERENCING OLD ROW AS Old, NEW ROW AS New FOR EACH ROW
     when(New.DELETED=1 AND New.ACTIVE=1)then
        UPDATE pUser SET ACTIVE = 0
     when (New.DELETED=0 AND New.ACTIVE=0)then
         UPDATE pUser SET ACTIVE = 1
         ;
```

Comment: witch DBMS are you using MSSQL?

Comment: Which dmbs? (That syntax doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: MSSQL looks like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375681/creating-a-trigger-with-a-case-statement

Comment: If this is SQl server, do not do row by ro w porcessing. ther is no reason at all not to do a set-based iperation.

Comment: "got error" isn't helpful to us - what error did you get, *specifically*? What was the message? Was there any additional information included?

Comment: Is this Oracle? If so then you need to either split this into two triggers or move the `WHEN` clause into the trigger body as an `IF` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Since SQL-2003 triggers have been included in the ANSI/ISO SQL specification. [ISO/IEC 9075-1:2011(E), "4.6.5.5 Triggers
A trigger is an object associated with a single base table or a single viewed table. A trigger specifies a subject table, trigger event, a trigger action time, and one or more triggered actions.
A trigger event specifies what action on the subject table shall cause the triggered actions. A trigger event is either INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE..."]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Oracle because of the syntax. I'm also assuming that you want to set a user to "active" when he is undeleted, and "inactive" when he is deleted. So we'll check when the `deleted` column in `pUser` is updated, and toggle `active` based upon that. And I think you want a `BEFORE` trigger here, not an `AFTER` one.

```
CREATE TRIGGER pUSer_update
BEFORE UPDATE OF deleted ON pUser
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 - new.deleted
    INTO :new.active
    FROM dual;
END;
/
```

You might need to refer to `new.deleted` with a colon (`:new.deleted`) in the `SELECT` (I can never remember which).

Comment: A direct assignment `:new.active := ...` is faster than a `select .. into ..`

Comment: True! I think that was first introduced in Oracle 11g (it could have been 10g), though, and the OP did not specify the DBMS.