# MySQL Trigger AFTER INSERT ON 'table name' FOR EACH ROW WHEN (role_id = 3)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to create trigger which is get specific role_id from table users and trigger insert into table get_roles_request and got some error.
Here is the structure Table[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5apt.png)

And Get Some error like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9gMI.png)

Comment: I don't think either MySQL or MariaDB allow the `WHEN` clause of the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

Comment: I got reference here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375681/creating-a-trigger-with-a-case-statement

Comment: That's Oracle my friend

Comment: can you please give me some idea to handle this?

Comment: Move the conditional into the body of the trigger

Comment: still got the same error
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER insert_role_request AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
WHERE (new.role_id = 3);
INSERT INTO get_roles_requests (user_id) VALUES (new.id);
END $
DELIMITER #

Comment: You need an `IF` not a `WHERE` - see @p-salmon's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Where is only available to a select , when is only available to a case. An if would do

```
DELIMITER $ 
CREATE TRIGGER insert_role_request AFTER INSERT ON users 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if (new.role_id = 3) then 
INSERT INTO get_roles_requests (user_id) VALUES (new.id); 
end if;
END $ 
DELIMITER ;
```